# Debugging a MFI application on the iPhone

Tags: ios, debugging, mfi

I am a MFi developer and I am developing an iPhone App that talks to custom hardware.
My question is how does one go about debugging the iPhone app

I have searched the web and stackoverflow but there seems to be no clear direction.

1.
30 Pin dock - 
Since the iPhone is docked to the accessory - how does Xcode debug the App

2.
There are some threads of Xcode debugging over  WiFi but this feature was there in Xcode but then removed - what is the state of this in the latest Xcode (Circa 2012)

Any direction especially from someone who has successfully done this would be appreciated.

Pedro

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging an iOS app with an external accessory connected via Dock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420716/debugging-an-ios-app-with-an-external-accessory-connected-via-dock)

Comment: Hello Tim - Yes I have see the other post - however that post is over two years old and I was wondering if there is any new development of this.  Seems like a fundamental problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless debugging was a feature in [Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266391/what-does-the-xcode-4-2-preference-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-do), but it has been removed in later versions, and it's still not available as of Xcode 5.0.
Looks like your best option is having to rely on logs, unfortunately.